# ASP.Net Core caching

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a .js file that is being statically served in my application. This file will continue to change through the course of development-

I had made some changes to the file this morning as I normally do. Debugging the project, I discovered that the changes in the .js were not reflected- i.e. the browser was using an older version of the javascript file.

I have been working on this project for a few weeks and the changes in the .js file have always been reflected in the next debug until today. I have tried in both Chrome and Edge.

What gives? I'm puzzled about the change in behavior. I did receive a Windows update overnight, could it be there's a global setting for browser caching which was previously disabled on my system and was enabled by the update. I am aware of cache busting techniques but in the past, I've always just been able to update the a static .js file and the browser has always used the latest .js file.

Comment: In my experience, the most likely explanation is user error; what usually happens is people update a different file, not the one that gets served. Can you check the network tab in your browser console? When the script is requested, are you getting status 200 or 304? What does the server response look like? What do you see when you type the script's URL in the address bar?

Comment: Chris G - Thanks for your suggestion. Launched the app this morning and it served the updated script file just fine in Chrome. I made some more changes to the same file and debugged again, watching the console window there were no requests for the script file and Chrome was using the cached version. Switched the debugger to IE- under IE the browser requests the script file which is the behavior I was expecting. So this appears to be an issue in Chrome and Edge but not IE.

Comment: I am currently experiencing this with MS Edge and haven't been able to figure out where the "old" version is cached.  I set a breakpoint in the modified file and run the app.  The breakpoint gets hit and Visual Studio Debugger activates, but is literally displaying a cached copy of the unchanged file.  I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, clearing my browser caches, and even deleting all the Temporary Inter Files under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files.  Nothing seems to work.  Somehow, the old file just shows up in the middle of debugging. #FRUSTRATED

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone else might find this helpful. I was poking around Visual Studio and in the "play button" next to IIS Express, there is a menu option called "Script Debugging" that I happened upon and was set to disabled. I enabled the setting and things are back to working as previously.

I was able to confirm that by disabling the setting, Chrome and Edge use a cached version of the script file.

My guess is a Windows update disabled the setting. Can someone explain how changing this setting in Visual Studio affects caching in browsers?

Comment: The server can send along header information that tells the browser whether the file is safe to cache or not: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Thanks, I never would  have found that button.  This seemed to solve all my problems.